# Is this sentence grammatically correct? and also is it the right way to use the word outrun?

Tags: grammar, vocabulary, tenses

Due to high demand buyers often outrun production of the phone.

Comment: I would not use "outrun" in that sentence. "Due to a high demand, the number of buyers often exceeds the number of phones being produced."

Comment: Maybe *overtake*, but with 100 phones produced, how can there be 101 actual buyers?